# How to use onclick event for a button generated through a template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

Testing `underscore.js`. Using its templating engine.  Problem is, I am unable to use the on-click listener, written with `jquery.AJAX` when the button is drawn from within the template. Here the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/underscore.js"></script>


<div id="HelloWorld">
    <h1>Hi There</h1>
    <a href="" id="helloThere">Say Hello</a>
    <div id="helloDiv"></div>
</div>

<script>
    $('a#helloThere').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var name='rickesh';
        var templateData=$('#sayHello').text();
        var compiled=_.template(templateData,{'data':name});
        $('#helloDiv').html(compiled);
    });

    $('button#helloAgain').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('hello again bro!!!');
    });
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="sayHello">
    Hello <%= data%> <br />
    <button id="helloAgain">Say Hello Again</button>
</script>
```

Now, in the above code when I click on  **SAY HELLO** link `<a href="" id="helloThere">Say Hello</a>`, the template is successful drawn and shows `Hello rickesh` along with a button. **But when I click on the button nothing happens**. Have I used the listener incorrectly? I want an action to be performed on the button click. Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use delegation with `.on()` :

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#helloAgain',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('hello again bro!!!');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create the event listener after creating the html element, probably like this :

```
$('a#helloThere').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var name='rickesh';
    var templateData=$('#sayHello').text();
    var compiled=_.template(templateData,{'data':name});
    $('#helloDiv').html(compiled);

    $('button#helloAgain').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('hello again bro!!!');
    });

});
```